# C# equivalent of Java Punctuation regex

Tags: c#, java, regex

I'm looking to find the equivalent in C# for the equivalent of this regex.

Java:

```
public static final String expression = "[\\s\\p{Punct}]";
```

`{Punct}` is a reserved character class in Java but I'm not sure how to create the equivalent expression so that the .net regex engine doesn't barf.

Answer (score 3):

`[\s\p{P}]` matches all whitespace and punctuation. Amusingly enough, it can be found in this exact form as an example in the MSDN documentation on [Character Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx). As in Java, `\p{x}` is used for any single character from unicode category `x`. See the part on [Unicode Categories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories) for a list of the possibilities other than `P`.

Comment: Heh... I came up with the exact same solution as you, although it is worth pointing out that this won't work like that. You need to use `@` before the string or else you need to escape the backslashes.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that, so I just edited out the quote marks. Now my post refers to the literal string values; how you denote these values in C# is a different matter. ;-) By the way, isn't the string in the question technically incorrect as well, for the same reason?

Comment: If you click edit you can see he wrote `"[\\s\\p{Punct}]"` but it formatted incorrectly. I'll edit the question so you can see what he intended to write.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I've found too. Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[\s\p{P}]");
```

Note in particular the use of `@`.