# C# Regular Expression to find multiple sequences of punctuation characters

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to match punctuations using regular expressions.

Do I have to specify every punctuation character I am searching for or is there is an escape sequence I can use?

I'm sitting here smiling to myself that the answers I might get will just be "Yes" or "No", please elaborate.... (that sentence should match the regular expression twice)

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705990/c-equivalent-of-java-punctuation-regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do i have to specify every punctuation character i am searching for or is there is an escape sequence i can use?

That would be a character class, not an escape sequence. You can use a character class defined by a Unicode category :

```
\p{P}
```

This expression matches characters in the category "All Punctuation". You can find a list of supported categories in the [`UnicodeCategory` enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.unicodecategory.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

found the answer, this is it

```
var m = Regex.Match(inputText.Substring(startPosition), @"(\p{P}){2,}");
```

Comment: You don't need to specify all sub-categories, since the `\p{P}` category includes all of them