# How would you translate this JavaScript regex to Java?

Tags: java, regex

How would you translate this JavaScript regex to Java?

It removes punctuation from a string:

```
strippedStr = str.replace(/[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't need the `s///` stuff in there, you just pass the regular expression, and here it's a character class.

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    String s = ".,/#!$%^&*;:{}=-_`~()./#hello#&%---#(($";
    String n = s.replaceAll("[-.,/#!$%^&*;:{}=_`~()]", "");
    System.out.println(n); // should print "hello"

    // using POSIX character class which matches any of:
    // !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
    String p = s.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "");
    System.out.println(p);
}
```

Syntax for Java Regular Expressions here:  http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

The POSIX character class used above covers a little more than you have, so I'm not sure if it fits your needs.

- **edited because you don't need to escape `.` in the character class.**
- **edited to move `-` to beginning of character class so it has no special meaning**

Comment: @Joey - that's what Java's documentation calls them, so I used their terminology.

Comment: @Joey: No, that is incorrect. Java-the-drooling-idiot maps the POSIX classes like `[[:punct:]]` into things that **look** like Unicode properties **but are not**.  So `\p{Punct}` is ASCII-only, not even the current locale.  You need to use `\fP` to access the Unicode `\p{Punctuation}` General Category.  Yes, I think it’s really stupid.

Comment: @Birryee: That will not work.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304928/unicode-equivalents-for-w-and-b-in-java-regular-expressions/4307261#4307261) for why.

Comment: @birryree: Your calling it a POSIX character class is reasonably accurate, since that’s like an ASCII-only `ctype.h`-type of function.  Unfortunately, it doesn’t work as well as one would like.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect this to work with all punctuation instead of just ASCII, you need to use:

```
String new_string = old_string.replaceAll("[\\pS\\pP]", "");
```

That’s because some of the things you are calling punctuation are actually symbols, as revealed by [my *uniprops* script](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uniprops):

```
$ uniprops - \\ . , / '#' ! '$' % ^ '&' '*' ';' : { } = _ '`' '~' '(' ')'
   U+002D ‹-› \N{ HYPHEN-MINUS }:
    \pP \p{Pd}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Common Zyyy Dash Dash_Punctuation Pd P Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Punct Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn PosixGraph PosixPrint PosixPunct Print Punctuation XPosixGraph XPosixPrint XPosixPunct
U+005C ‹\› \N{ REVERSE SOLIDUS }:
    \pP \p{Po}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Common Zyyy Po P Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Other_Punctuation Punct Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn PosixGraph PosixPrint PosixPunct Print Punctuation XPosixGraph XPosixPrint XPosixPunct
U+002E ‹.› \N{ FULL STOP }:
    \pP \p{Po}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Case_Ignorable CI Common Zyyy Po P Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Other_Punctuation Punct Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn PosixGraph PosixPrint PosixPunct Print Punctuation STerm Term Terminal_Punctuation XPosixGraph XPosixPrint XPosixPunct
U+002C ‹,› \N{ COMMA }:
    \pP \p{Po}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Common Zyyy Po P Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Other_Punctuation Punct Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn PosixGraph PosixPrint PosixPunct Print Punctuation Term Terminal_Punctuation XPosixGraph XPosixPrint XPosixPunct
U+002F ‹/› \N{ SOLIDUS }:
    \pP \p{Po}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Common Zyyy Po P Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Other_Punctuation Punct Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn PosixGraph PosixPrint PosixPunct Print Punctuation XPosixGraph XPosixPrint XPosixPunct
U+0023 ‹#› \N{ NUMBER SIGN }:
    \pP \p{Po}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Common Zyyy Po P Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Other_Punctuation Punct Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn PosixGraph PosixPrint PosixPunct Print Punctuation XPosixGraph XPosixPrint XPosixPunct
U+0021 ‹!› \N{ EXCLAMATION MARK }:
    \pP \p{Po}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Common Zyyy Po P Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Other_Punctuation Punct Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn PosixGraph PosixPrint PosixPunct Print Punctuation STerm Term Terminal_Punctuation XPosixGraph XPosixPrint XPosixPunct
U+0024 ‹$› \N{ DOLLAR SIGN }:
    \pS \p{Sc}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Common Zyyy Currency_Symbol Sc S Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn PosixGraph PosixPrint PosixPunct Print Symbol XPosixGraph XPosixPrint XPosixPunct
U+0025 ‹%› \N{ PERCENT SIGN }:
    \pP \p{Po}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Common Zyyy Po P Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Other_Punctuation Punct Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn PosixGraph PosixPrint PosixPunct Print Punctuation XPosixGraph XPosixPrint XPosixPunct
U+005E ‹^› \N{ CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT }:
    \pS \p{Sk}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Case_Ignorable CI Common Zyyy Dia Diacritic Sk S Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Math Modifier_Symbol Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn PosixGraph PosixPrint PosixPunct Print Symbol XPosixGraph XPosixPrint XPosixPunct
U+0026 ‹&› \N{ AMPERSAND }:
    \pP \p{Po}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Common Zyyy Po P Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Other_Punctuation Punct Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn PosixGraph PosixPrint PosixPunct Print Punctuation XPosixGraph XPosixPrint XPosixPunct
U+002A ‹*› \N{ ASTERISK }:
    \pP \p{Po}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Common Zyyy Po P Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Other_Punctuation Punct Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn PosixGraph PosixPrint PosixPunct Print Punctuation XPosixGraph XPosixPrint XPosixPunct
U+003B ‹;› \N{ SEMICOLON }:
    \pP \p{Po}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Common Zyyy Po P Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Other_Punctuation Punct Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn PosixGraph PosixPrint PosixPunct Print Punctuation Term Terminal_Punctuation XPosixGraph XPosixPrint XPosixPunct
U+003A ‹:› \N{ COLON }:
    \pP \p{Po}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Case_Ignorable CI Common Zyyy Po P Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Other_Punctuation Punct Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn PosixGraph PosixPrint PosixPunct Print Punctuation Term Terminal_Punctuation XPosixGraph XPosixPrint XPosixPunct
U+007B ‹{› \N{ LEFT CURLY BRACKET }:
    \pP \p{Ps}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Bidi_M Bidi_Mirrored BidiM Common Zyyy Ps P Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Open_Punctuation Punct Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn PosixGraph PosixPrint PosixPunct Print Punctuation XPosixGraph XPosixPrint XPosixPunct
U+007D ‹}› \N{ RIGHT CURLY BRACKET }:
    \pP \p{Pe}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Bidi_M Bidi_Mirrored BidiM Close_Punctuation Pe Common Zyyy P Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Punct Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn PosixGraph PosixPrint PosixPunct Print Punctuation XPosixGraph XPosixPrint XPosixPunct
U+003D ‹=› \N{ EQUALS SIGN }:
    \pS \p{Sm}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Common Zyyy Sm S Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Math Math_Symbol Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn PosixGraph PosixPrint PosixPunct Print Symbol XPosixGraph XPosixPrint XPosixPunct
U+005F ‹_› \N{ LOW LINE }:
    \w \pP \p{Pc}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Common Zyyy Connector_Punctuation Pc P Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase ID_Continue IDC Punct PerlWord PosixGraph PosixPrint PosixPunct PosixWord Print Punctuation Word XID_Continue XIDC XPosixGraph XPosixPrint XPosixPunct XPosixWord
U+0060 ‹`› \N{ GRAVE ACCENT }:
    \pS \p{Sk}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Case_Ignorable CI Common Zyyy Dia Diacritic Sk S Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Modifier_Symbol Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn PosixGraph PosixPrint PosixPunct Print Symbol XPosixGraph XPosixPrint XPosixPunct
U+007E ‹~› \N{ TILDE }:
    \pS \p{Sm}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Common Zyyy Sm S Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Math Math_Symbol Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn PosixGraph PosixPrint PosixPunct Print Symbol XPosixGraph XPosixPrint XPosixPunct
U+0028 ‹(› \N{ LEFT PARENTHESIS }:
    \pP \p{Ps}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Bidi_M Bidi_Mirrored BidiM Common Zyyy Ps P Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Open_Punctuation Punct Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn PosixGraph PosixPrint PosixPunct Print Punctuation XPosixGraph XPosixPrint XPosixPunct
U+0029 ‹)› \N{ RIGHT PARENTHESIS }:
    \pP \p{Pe}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Bidi_M Bidi_Mirrored BidiM Close_Punctuation Pe Common Zyyy P Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase Punct Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn PosixGraph PosixPrint PosixPunct Print Punctuation XPosixGraph XPosixPrint XPosixPunct
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a Java guy but:

```
public static final String expression = "[\\s\\p{Punct}]";
```

Source: [C# equivalent of Java Punctuation regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705990/c-equivalent-of-java-punctuation-regex)

Comment: That doesn’t work for reasons I commented on elsewhere.  The right way to is to use `\pP`, but for `\s`, you have to pass it through my [Unicode-enabling Java-regex rewriting function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304928/unicode-equivalents-for-w-and-b-in-java-regular-expressions/4307261#4307261), which will correct any `\s` to read `[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0020\u0085\u00A0\u1680\u180E\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200A\u2028\u2029\u202F\u205F\u3000]`.

Answer (score 0):

The `g` at the end of the regexp means it's global; the equivalent Java `String` method is [`replaceAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll) (which takes a search regexp and a replacement string). The only thing you need to do to the regexp itself is escape the `\`s, since the Java parser will interpret things like `\.` as you trying to escape a `.`:

```
String strippedStr = str.replaceAll("[\\.,-\\/#!$%\\^&\\*;:{}=\\-_`~()]", "");
```

Comment: An alternative to backslashing that and that metacharacter, you could use the `\Q` metaquoting translation escape, which Java processed during pattern compilation.  That would let you use simply `"[\\Q.,-/#!$%^&*;:{}=-_ˋ~()\\E]"` as the first argument to your function.  Also, you would not need to escape anything but the `-` or an initial `^` in a square-bracketed character class.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this character class get the job done in a more concise way?

```
str.replaceAll("[\\W_]", "");
```

Comment: ’Fraid not. [Java’s character-class shortcuts are broken when used on Java’s own native character set!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304928/unicode-equivalents-for-w-and-b-in-java-regular-expressions/4307261#4307261)